# show data table value from listbox in vb.net

Tags: vb.net, ado.net

I have a list box ..if i select any item i want to get that in my datatable
so i given code like this:

```
 Dim dtlist As New DataTable()
        Dim locid As Integer
        If cnt > 0 Then
            For i = 0 To cnt - 1
                Dim locationanme As String = LSTlocations.SelectedItems(i).ToString
                locid = RecordID("Locid", "Location_tbl", "LocName", locationanme)
                dtlist.Columns.Add(locid)
            Next
           end if
```

then i want check my datatable contains my listbox selected value..and i want to show that values how i can do that?

Answer (score 0):

Use CheckedListBox. In that you can achieve what you needed using the property,

'Can get Index of any i th item with below code
chklistbox1.CheckedIndices(i)

'Can get value of any ith item as string with below code
chklistbox1.CheckedItems(i).ToString